# SPARQL wikidata group-by: get grouped items in the answer (rivers with multiple cities)

Tags: sparql, aggregation, wikidata-query-service

The following query returns rivers with at least 3 big cities on them.

[try it on wikidata query service](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20rivers%20and%20cities%0ASELECT%20%3Friver%20%3FriverLabel%20%28COUNT%28%3Fcity%29%20AS%20%3Fcitycount%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Friver%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ4022.%20%23%20...%20is%20a%20river%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ1549591.%20%23%20...%20is%20a%20big%20city%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP206%20%3Friver.%20%20%23%20...%20located%20in%20or%20next%20to%20body%20of%20water%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Friver%20%3FriverLabel%0AHAVING%20%28%3Fcitycount%20%3E%3D%203%29%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fcitycount%29%0A)

```sql
# rivers with at least 3 big cities

SELECT ?river ?riverLabel (COUNT(?city) AS ?citycount)
WHERE {
  ?river wdt:P31 wd:Q4022. # ... is a river
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q1549591. # ... is a big city
  ?city wdt:P206 ?river.  # ... located in or next to body of water
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]".}
}
GROUP BY ?river ?riverLabel
HAVING (?citycount >= 3)    # ← important line
ORDER BY DESC(?citycount)
```

How can I include the actual cities (and their labels) in the answer? The ordering should stay the same, i.e. the first 13 results should be the cities located at Yangtze river, the next 11 results those at Rhine etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `GROUP_CONCAT`, see below.

```
# rivers and cities
SELECT ?river ?riverLabel (COUNT(?city) AS ?citycount)
(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(STR(?city), "--> ", ?cityLabel); SEPARATOR="; ") AS ?cities)
WHERE {
  ?river wdt:P31 wd:Q4022. # ... is a river
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q1549591. # ... is a big city
  ?city wdt:P206 ?river.  # ... located in or next to body of water
  ?city rdfs:label ?cityLabel .
  FILTER(LANG(?cityLabel) = 'en')
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]".}
}
GROUP BY ?river ?riverLabel
HAVING (?citycount >= 3)
ORDER BY DESC(?citycount)
```

Comment: the ordering might not be preserved though in the `group_concat` function which is a known limitation of SPARQL 1.1 - which means some could have `c1;c2` and others `c2;c1` which would be after `c1;c3` then

Comment: From cknoll's message it seems to me that he wants the ordering of the rivers to stay the same, i.e. show the river with the most cities first. As for the ordering of cities within a `GROUP_CONCAT`, it doesn't look like cknoll is too bothered.

Comment: There seems to be a closing bracket too much in the SELECT statement and SO does not allow 3rd party edits  below 6 characters...

Comment: This is an very interesting solution which I did not have in mind. I thought it would be possible (probably with multiple select statements) to generate a result where every city has its own row.

Comment: Sorry about the brackets, it's fixed now. You can generate a query where every city has its own row too of course. You'd probably need a subquery where you compute how many cities a river has, and the select the river, its number of cities, and its cities, one per row.